# How to redirect to the absolute URL of a model instance while appending a hash?

Tags: python, django, redirect, fragment-identifier

I have a view that ends with the following line:

```
#...
item = get_an_item_from_the_db()
return redirect(item)
```

This should return an `HttpResponseRedirect` that redirects the client to the following page:

```
/item/12/
```

However, I would like to append a hash to the end of the URL:

```
/item/12/#bottom
```

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return redirect(item.get_absolute_url() + '#hash')
```